# What's the right approach for multi-level lazy loaded data for React Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-query, react-table-v7

I have been working with React Query and React Table recently to achieve a multi-level table structure with expandable rows, where each row should do lazy loading when clicked on. It's for product group hierarchy, which looks like this:

```
unit-1 (clicking fetches category data lazily)
  category-1 (clicking fetches product data lazily)
    product-1
    product-2
  category-2
    product-3
unit-2
  category-3
    product-4
    product-5
```

I have two options for the solution:

- **Sub components lazy load example for React Table** (https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/sub-components-lazy)
  This focuses on only one level of depth, so I am not sure how to make it multi-level due to the fact that I am still not very familiar with the React Table API and it seems like the example was not created with that purpose. I tried making it multi-level but I had difficulty in passing some row properties around like (.isExpanded, .id, etc)
- **A post about manipulating the data by each row click so that rest is handled automatically by the table** (https://nafeu.medium.com/lazy-loading-expandable-rows-with-react-table-cd2fc86b0630 - GitHub ex: https://github.com/nafeu/react-query-table-sandbox/blob/main/src/ReactTableExpanding.jsx)
  This seems to be a more declarative way to handle things. (We fetch new data, merge it with the existing data and the rest is handled) but I have some concerns like if updating the whole table data causes unnecessary renders. Another thing is since we don't render a sub-component here as in the first one, the API endpoint should be arranged to work with a click event. It's not like having a sub-component that is responsible for fetching its own data when it's mounted.

As a note for the table example above, I was planning to use a single API endpoint that takes params like:

```
?level=root&id=0 (initial units list data for the table on page load)
?level=unit&id=2 (returns categories of unit-2) 
...
```

But this logic doesn't seem enough for supporting fetching on row click so I guess I'll need at least two endpoints if I follow the second approach.

Thanks for reading, and any ideas are welcome!
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

As an update, I could make things work mostly with the second option above. As a note on the API endpoints, I could use the same API endpoint and the same hook twice with different parameters. (this part is a bit project specific of course but maybe it gives an idea to the ones having similar scenarios)

To get the initial data for the table, I give hardcoded parameters to the hook, so that the table is rendered with the initialData on page load.

```
const { data: initialData, isLoading } = useGetLevels(
  {
    level: 'root',
    id: [0],
    ...
  }
 );
```

In the second one, I use enabled: false, and when a row is clicked on I call refetch(), so additional data is fetched and merged with the initial data to update the table and the row is expanded accordingly:

```
const {
  data: partialData,
  refetch,
} = useGetLevels(
  {
    level,
    id,
    ...
  },
  false
);
```

and the useGetLevels look like this:

```
function useGetLevels(
filterParams,
enabled
) {
return useQuery(
  ['levels', filterParams],
  () => fetchLevels(filterParams),
  {
    enabled,
  }
);
}
```

Comment: Thank you~ Added, you might delete your comment so it will not get fed into GPT or something.